# How do i display directional data after initial load?

Tags: angular, mapbox

I have a map that I want to show directional data on.

### template

```html
<mgl-map class="map" [style]="style" [zoom]="zoom" [center]="center">
    <mgl-geojson-source id="geojson-route">
        <mgl-feature [geometry]="route"></mgl-feature>
    </mgl-geojson-source>
    <mgl-layer id="route" type="line" source="geojson-route" [layout]="layout" [paint]="paint">
    </mgl-layer>
</mgl-map>
```

### component

If I hard-code the data to variable route then it works with the above code:

```js
route = {"type":"LineString","coordinates": coords}
```

However, I am wanting to dynamically set the coordinates when my service returns like this:

```js
this.mapService.getDirections(profile, coordinates).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.route = data;
            });
```

However, doing the above does not work, no errors are shown and no coordinates are shown?

Am I missing something?

ref:

- https://github.com/Wykks/ngx-mapbox-gl
- https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/overview/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try do not render the component until the `route` has been initialized with `*ngIf`:

**template**:

```
<div *ngIf="route">
  <mgl-map class="map" [style]="style" [zoom]="zoom" [center]="center">
    <mgl-geojson-source id="geojson-route">
        <mgl-feature [geometry]="route"></mgl-feature>
    </mgl-geojson-source>
    <mgl-layer id="route" type="line" source="geojson-route" [layout]="layout" [paint]="paint">
    </mgl-layer>
  </mgl-map>
</div>
```

Then after the subscription:

```
this.mapService.getDirections(profile, coordinates).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.route = data;
            });
```

is complete, the `*ngIf` will be true and your map will be rendered with the data you load from `this.mapService.getDirections`.

Answer (score 0):

All `mgl-feature`'s properties are "init only", according to https://github.com/Wykks/ngx-mapbox-gl/wiki/API-Documentation#ngx-mgl-feature-inside-mgl-geojson-source-only. I'd suggest using `data` property of the source instead:

```
<mgl-map class="map" [style]="style" [zoom]="zoom" [center]="center">
    <mgl-geojson-source id="geojson-route" [data]="route">
    </mgl-geojson-source>
    <mgl-layer id="route" type="line" source="geojson-route" [layout]="layout" [paint]="paint">
    </mgl-layer>
</mgl-map>
```

then make sure your `route` variable has proper shape (`GeoJSON.Feature` in this case):

```
route = {
   "type": "Feature",
   "geometry": {
       "type":"LineString",
       "coordinates": coords
   }
}
```